# android code for zooming image in framelayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design

I am trying to zoom in and zoom out images from recyclerview to a framelayout. The problem is, image zooms at it place very well but I am not able to display it in framelayout (just image visible on the screen with translucent grey background), below is the codebase please have a look and suggest.

**View Holder**

```
 public ViewHolderQuestions(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            imgzoom = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        }
```

**OnBindViewHolder**

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderQuestions holder, final int position) {
      holder.qImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setAnimation(holder.qImage, position);
            }
        });
    }
```

**setAnimation method**

```
private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position){
            animationIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(layoutInflater.getContext(), R.anim.zoom_in);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animationIn);
       }
```

Comment: Would you be interested in a library ? PhotoViewAttacher: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: @Miriana I did not used this library just because it says this is deprecation.